# MS SQL Server Management Studio 2014, with older (2012) version of SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am using locally the MS SQL Server Management Studio 2012 with SQL server 2012 database engine.

I have the following question:

Can I upgrade **ONLY** the SQL Server Management Studio 2012 (TOOLS) to 2014 version, and leave my old 2012 already installed database engine version?

Comment: Yes, you can update only your Management Tool and let your database engine stay old 2012.

Comment: Yes, you can. you can download SSMS 2014 separately from MS.

Comment: SSMS is a standalone product now, the latest version is 16.5.3 and it *does* work with any database from 2008 upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yes, you can.

But install SSMS 2014 as **standalone** (instead of trying to **upgrade** tools).

From [SSMS 2014 SP1 release notes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3058865/sql-server-2014-service-pack-1-release-information) you can see that it vitally supported SQL Server 2012. See how many compatibility fixes for 2012 were delivered.

Generally I'd recommend to prefer [latest release of SSMS 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) which

> works with all supported versions of SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 - SQL Server 2016)

(Besides that I tried to find similar statement for SSMS 2014 (there was one), but I couldn't.)

I'm using SSMS 2008 + SSMS 2016 side by side and they are running just fine. In similar way, I was using SSMS 2008 + SSMS 2014 before the upgrade.

Comment: @user2986570 – I wrote about successfully using two different SSMS versions concurrently. Uninstallation shouldn't be necessary unless you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install SQL Server Management Studio using the links provided in: Scott Hanselman's website

There are links to various SSMS versions (2012, 2014, for x86, x64), as well as links to various SQL-Server Express versions.

By the way, you can use the latest SSMS 2014 to manage your 2012 database.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply install new SSMS 2014 version and leave the 2012 version installed **ONLY IF** they are all 32-bit or 64-bit. You cannot upgrade 32-bit 2012 to 64-bit 2014 and vice versa. Ideally you could use 2014 version SSMS to access databases created in 2012 before because of the compatible level allows you to do that, but it will raise another problem for restoring the databases since you cannot restore any backup files that backed up from old(2012) to (2014) because of the database version did not match.

Comment: No need ror this. SSMS supports older versions. Bitness doesn't matter either. SSMS is 32-bit only and just a client anyway

Comment: there is 64 bit ver. for SSMS 2014 express. and I think there would be a concern if op needs to restore any old backup files from 2012.

Comment: No there isn't. You are confusing `SQL Server` with `SQL Server Management Studio` which is a 32-bit application. SSMS is the *IDE*, not the server

Comment: GOTO -1. You are confusing the *server* with the IDE. SSMS [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

Answer (score 0):

SSMS is now a [separate free product](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) that works with all versions from 2008 and up. The current version is 16.5.3

For older versions:

> There is no explicit block for SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005, but some features may not work properly.

You'll have to download the RC version if you want to connect to SQL Server vNext, eg to SQL Server on Linux